# how to DRY chained ActiveRecord calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Consider this bit of code:

```
if ids.blank?
  UptimeSummary.
    where("start_time >= ?", start_time).
    group(:uptime_monitor_id).
    select("uptime_monitor_id, sum(uptime)/count(*) AS uptime_average")
else
  UptimeSummary.
    where(:uptime_monitor_id => ids).
    where("start_time >= ?", start_time).
    group(:uptime_monitor_id).
    select("uptime_monitor_id, sum(uptime)/count(*) AS uptime_average")
end
```

The only difference between the two clauses is the additional `(:uptime_monitor_id => ids)` in the latter clause.

This seems rather un-DRY.  How can I clean that up?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out an answer as I was typing in the question.  Because the calls to ActiveRecord query chains are deferred, you can do this:

```
q = UptimeSummary.
      where("start_time >= ?", start_time).
      group(:uptime_monitor_id).
      select("uptime_monitor_id, sum(uptime)/count(*) AS uptime_average")
q = q.where(:uptime_monitor_ids => ids) unless ids.blank?
```

If you know of cleaner approach, I'd love to learn about it.